# What is data-cip-id in ASP.NET MVC and how do I remove it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Been trying to find information about this with no luck.

When using a html helper in ASP.NET MVC to generate a textbox as such:

```
@Html.TextBox("Test")
```

I always get

```
 <input id="Test" name="Test" type="text" value="" data-cip-id="Test">
```

What is this ugly data-cip-id? What function does it have and how do I remove it?

Comment: newly created MVC project. I only have resharper installed.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried running your browser with all the extensions disabled (for example, by using incognito mode in Chrome)?

Comment: lol, seems like its something added by the extension "chromeIPass", when I disabled it there is no data-cip-id anymore. Thanks Tom! If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [ChromeIPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae) browser extension for Chrome dynamically adds `data-cip-id` attributes to elements on web pages as you view them.

The extension provides [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) integration into the Chrome browser, allowing you to populate username & password fields on websites directly from your KeePass Password Safe database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've attached any JS library that is adding this property to your text box. Check for referenced JS libraries in rendered HTML and you'll be fine.